# How do I get the BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() working on my Android 10 device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I'm trying to get any bluetooth device around myself with my Huawei P30 (Android 10). When I try to use `bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` it always returns false. I found out that the problem was the permission `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` which were not working. So I tried to use every solutions described on this link : [Android - Bluetooth discovery doesn't find any device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966133/android-bluetooth-discovery-doesnt-find-any-device), but unfortunatly, nothing works, the application doesn't start to scan.
Finally, I got the permissions but the function still returns false and the discovery doesn't start... Does any one have a solution for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem on an Android 10 Huawei device. Even though I was not using location services in the app. In addition to adding the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in the AndroidManifest.xml I also had to

1. Grant permission to the app for location.
2. Turn on location services in the system settings. Which of course grants always on location access to a bunch of services and apps which can't be disabled within the OS.

It would be good to know if this behaviour is for Android 10 in general or a specific Huawei quirk.

Comment: I've all ready tried that but it still doesn't work... I'm juste stuck on the scanner for Android 10, and if it's not working, my app can not be developped...

Comment: I've finnally got it working ! I just didn't check in the Java code if the permission is granted or not, and I didn't asked for it if it's not activated... Thanks for your help !